# Understanding the Alloy Visualizer's display of a relation created using the arrow operator

Tags: alloy

To help me understand the arrow (product) operator, I created a model of WhitePages. Each white page has a mapping from names to addresses (this name/address mapping uses the arrow operator). I created a predicate to show the name/address mapping for a white page *w*. In the predicate I specified the number of name/address associations is 3. See model below.

According to the definition of the arrow operator, the Name->Address relation contains all combinations of names and addresses. So, as I see it, there is only one possible instance:

[image]

Surprisingly, instead of that, the Visualizer gave this:

[image]

That doesn't look like a valid instance to me. Where are the Name/Address mappings?

```
sig WhitePages {
    address: Name->Address
}

sig Name {}

sig Address {}

pred Show (w: WhitePages) {#w.address = 3}

run Show
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You projected it over Address, so you now have one snapshot for each address. You'll see a UI control at the bottom to let you choose the address. Note that your constraint says that there are 3 pairs in the name-address relation, so they can be distributed across different addresses.